# Правильный ли ход разработки?

Tags: python, websocket, asyncio, zeromq, aiohttp

**У меня система должна работать таким образом:**

1. клиент через браузер проводит транзакцию (переводит деньги)
2. сервер принимает данные и обрабатывает их
3. сервер отправляет данные второму серверу (дублирует данные для сохранности данных). таких серверов может быть сотни.
4. возвращается ответ клиенту в браузер о выполнении перевода

**Правильный ли ход моей разработки?**

1. перевод от клиента через браузер, *отправляю данные на сервер через websocket*
2. сервер получает данные от браузера через websocket, создает поток asyncio(*например с использование aiohttp в python*), в потоке выполняет обработку транзакции и записывает в базу данных
3. этот сервер отправляет другим серверам эти данные с использование zeroMQ
4. последний сервер, получив данные и записав их, через websocket сообщает браузеру, что перевод совершен

*Что не так в этих этапах разработки?*

Comment: Че там с кодом, Чарли?

Comment: @jfs, жду совета)

Comment: @misdeed, мне нужен совет, правильно ли я составил план разработки

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно взять книгу по проектирования приложений на основе веб-серверной архитектуры, и прочесть что такое ассинхронный ответ от сервера.

Comment: @Евгений Иванов, поправил вопрос, те места где ошибки сделал курсивом.

Comment: Что если с другими серверами не получится связаться и/или zeroMQ сломается?

Comment: @andreymal, клиент отправляет данные серверу - сервер бродкастит остальные. те сервера, которые отвалились пропускаются и это уже их задача вернутся к жизни и получить последние данные у соседей. (в данном случае попытка сделать блокчейн криптовалюту)

Comment: @ЕгорЛапицкий: Вопрос слишком общий, чтобы информативный ответ дать. Советы стараюсь не давать, только информировать, но раз вы явно попросили: научитесь сперва работать с уже существующими приложениями/популярными типами приложений, где за вас уже архитектуру придумали и основные решения по реализации приняты (к примеру, для веб-приложений начните с django, даже если для вашего текущего приложения это не нужно и даже если в будущем вы только pyramid, flask, bottle, etc будете использовать). Посмотрите какие приложения/framework похожи на то что вы в серверной части делаете, какие они решения

Comment: принимают. Затем можно уже сравнивать какие разные решения в разных местах приняты и почему.

Comment: второй сервер не ответит клиенту, вэбсокет соединение с первым сервером было